# At least K successes in n tries without replacement

Tags: probability

A bit surprisingly I can't find the answer to exactly my question. I am looking for the formula to calculate at least k successes with n tries without replacement.

For example take the bag/balls problems. Let's say 250000 balls in the bag 250 white 249750 blue. If you draw 8500 balls what is the probability of drawing at least 1 white ball.

Comment: More detail is needed.

Comment: Okay no problem.

Comment: It might be worth looking up the hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count of favoured items in a sample selected from a population *without replacement* has a **hypergeometric distribution**.

When the population is size $N$ with $K$ favoured items, and the sample is of size $n$, then the count $W$ of favoured items in the sample having size $k$ has probability:

$$\mathsf P(W=k) = \dfrac{\dbinom{K}{k}~\dbinom{N-K}{n-k}}{\dbinom{N}{n}} \qquad \Big[0\leq k\leq \min(K, n) \leq \max(K, n) \leq N\Big]$$

$$\mathsf P(W\geqslant k) = \sum_{x=k}^{\min(K, n)} \dfrac{\dbinom{K}{x}~\dbinom{N-K}{n-x}}{\dbinom{N}{n}} \qquad \Big[0\leq k\leq \min(K, n) \leq \max(K, n) \leq N\Big]$$

For particular values it might be more appropriate to use an approximation, or work with the complement, to ease the computation load.

> For example take the bag/balls problems. Let's say 250000 balls in the bag 250 white 249750 blue. If you draw 8500 balls what is the probability of drawing at least 1 white ball.

This is easiest calculated using the complement.   It is the probability of *not* drawing zero white balls.

$$\mathsf P(W\geqslant 1) = 1-\mathsf P(W=0) = 1-\dfrac{\binom{250}{0}\binom{249750}{8500}}{\binom{250000}{8500}}\\ \approx 0.999{\small 825266071400062267418017708833099206480271885565627713\ldots}$$

Comment: when I am trying to calculate the probability here using the following formula on wolfram alpha: 1-(nCr(250,0)*nCr(294750,8500))/nCr(250000,8500) I do not get the same answer as you did.

Comment: When I calculate the P without nCr(250,0) now I get the correct answer.

Comment: I have no idea what you were doing wrong.  $^{250}{\rm C}_{0} = 1$ so its exclusion should not make a jot of difference @TheNightman

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{j=K}^N p^j \cdot (1-p)^{N-j}\cdot {N \choose j}$$ where $p$ is the probability of a success.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the term j=k. Are you just saying that j and k are the same, being number of picks?

Comment: j runs from $K$ to $N$. You need at least K successes. So $K+1$ is also a valid state and so on

Comment: I'm not sure why this is not working but here is the computation I'm using (250000 balls choose 2500): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(0.001%5Ex*(1-0.001)%5E(250000-x)*nCr(250000,x),x,2500,250000)

Comment: This uses the Binomial Distribution, which is for successes in selections *with* replacement.  Although this *is* a reasonably good approximation when $N$ is much larger than $n$ and $K$ is not too small.